# Replace characters after match with sed

Tags: text-processing, sed, regular-expression, whitespace

I have a string:

```
172.16.1.5] "80 EE 73 2F 0B 40
```

I need to replace all the spaces after the `] "` with a colon. Currently using `sed -r 's/[ ]+/:/g'` I get an output of `172.16.1.5]:"80:EE:73:2F:0B:40:`, however I need to keep the first space after the bracket.

How can I replace all the instances of a character, but only after a match using sed?

Comment: end of string is `0B:40:` after sed. Why the colon at end of string? There's no `] "` at end of original string.

Comment: @suspectus I think there is a space at the end that is getting replaced

Comment: ok, I read "I need to replace all the spaces after the ] " with a colon" literally.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are different approaches possible.

A conditional loop, that replaces one space at a time:

```
sed -e :1 -e 's/\(\] .*\) /\1:/; t1'
```

Saving the prefix, remove it, substitution, restore prefix:

```
sed '/\] /{ s//&\
/; h; s/.*\n//; s/ /:/g; H; g; s/\n.*\n//;}'
```

Neither will do any substitution if the input doesn't contain `"] "`.

Answer (score 1):

you could use

```
echo '172.16.1.5] "80 EE 73 2F 0B 40' | sed -r 's/ +/:/g;s/\]:/\] /g'
```

to have

```
172.16.1.5] "80:EE:73:2F:0B:40
```